# Как массово заменить фразы в csv файле, если фразы которые нужно заменить лежат в другом файле?

Tags: shell, csv, sed, awk

Подскажите как можно массово заменить фразы в csv файле

если есть второй файл в котором указанны фраза которую заменить на фразу которой заменить 
в виде списка:

```
что заменить|чем заменить
```

Comment: @Mike, всего два процесса *sed* отлично справятся с любым (в пределах разумного) количеством строк за один «проход». см. мой ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin А, точно. мне почему то всегда кажется, что ему можно указать только одну замену :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так:

```
$ sed -f <(sed 's/^/s|/;s/$/|/' файл-с-заменами) исходный-файл > результат
```

---

пояснения:

- `sed 's/^/s|/;s/$/|/'` — превращает строки файла с заменами в полноценные команды на языке интерпретатора *sed*: `что заменить|чем заменить` преобразуется в `s|что заменить|чем заменить|`
- `-f имя-или-дескритор-файла` — указывает интерпретатору *sed* читать программу из указанного файла или дескриптора
- `<(команда)` — из этой конструкции оболочка создаёт дескриптор файла и подключает к нему стандартный вывод (*stdout*) указанной команды

Comment: Подскажите как сделать чтобы игнорировался регистр заменяемых слов, добавляю "-i" после "-f"  , но получаю ошибку : "sed: невозможно открыть файл -i: No such file or directory", ввожу так: $ sed -f -i <(sed 's/^/s|/;s/$/|/' файл-с-заменами) исходный-файл > результат

Comment: @Новичок, игнорирование регистра в команде `s` указывается с помощью флага `i`. т.е., вам надо преобразовывать строки к виду: `s|что заменить|чем заменить|i`.

Comment: то есть вставить "i" после "|" в этом коде 's/^/s|/;s/$/|/' чтобы получилось 's/^/s|/;s/$/|i/'

Comment: Вроде работает, спасибо